# How to write a program that detects address of files that were copied to a USB drive?

Tags: usb-drive

I want to write a program that detects address of files that were copied to a USB drive? I want to Every time files were copied to a USB,address of files show in console .How can i do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "address of files"?  In what language do you plan to write the program - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to write a progran in c#

Comment: For example when i want to copy one file from drive C to USB drive I want to show the name and address of this current file that is copying to USB

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the language you chose to use for the job, but regardless you would want to use a library that watches the filesystem for changes and runs a method when a new file is added. If you provide more information about what you want, we can probably give you a more precise answer.

Comment: It seems that Oracle provides a tutorial for doing a very similar thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Thanks but have you other recources?,because Oracle boycott iran and we can not achieve Oracle recourses

Comment: Try this: http://blog.philippheckel.com/2014/06/17/recursively-watch-folders-using-java-7-watchservice/

Comment: Exceuse me i want to write this program in c#

Comment: In that case C# provides the FileSystemWatcher class for this purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396